# How to merge results from distribute worker in tf.distribute.experimental.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy

Tags: tensorflow, distribute

tf.distribute.experimental.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy
how to get all the results from distributed workers in tf2.0

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Complete guidelines on how to use tf.distribute.multiWorkerMirroredStrategy` is given in [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/multi_worker_with_keras). Thanks!